Joning three pieces at 120 degrees angle
I build a prototype of a three legged stool.

I am pretty happy with how it ended up, the next time I will have a slightly bigger angle on the legs, so they point a bit more outwards, used 7.5 degrees, maybe 10ish.
But, my question is on the three pointed star holding the legs together. I just did a three way butt joint with glue. Quite difficult to do and not the strongest join. I have been trying to find out other ways to do that join, I've seen some people secure it with a couple of screws, but I do not like that idea. Basically, I have two ideas:

A three way lap joint, some interesting geometry, but doable. Maybe even secure it with a dovel when it is put together.

Using either a triangle or a cylinder in the middle and either do mortise/tenon joints or by a dovetail groove in the centre piece and slide the arm in.


Anybody having some other ideas or any advices on the ideas I've had so far? I've seen the three way bridle joint which is really cool and close to what I want, but not quite.

I've not heard of the bridle joint before.  While not simple it looks like it might be doable.  I think I've seen the three way dovetail approach on old items such as a hat rack.  I've no idea how to go about making a sliding dovetail where the joint has a rounded edge.  Sliding dovetails where the center piece is a three, six or even twelve sided block would be an alternative to trying a sliding dovetail on a round surface.

Your existing three-way joint may be quite a bit stronger than you're thinking if done accurately and clamped well during glue-up. Either way, as for every joint, the important thing is is it strong enough for the required purpose? As-is, it could well be. But if you feel it isn't it is quite easy to come up with multiple options for strengthening it, both simply and quickly. That aside, if you think this joint is quite difficult don't you think all the options you're presenting are more difficult? The three-way bridle is by comparison insanely difficult, no?

@quill, bridle joints are also referred to as open mortise-and-tenon joints. They're used more now than they once were, but have never been a major joint (numerous older books don't mention them, by either name). They are in their way as hard to do as more conventional M&Ts, are considered less strong and in traditional aesthetics less desirable. Obviously that last one is something that has changed considerably in modern times. FWIW a shouldered halving joint (half-lap) may be as strong or stronger in the needed axis and is considerably easier to do.

Now your Question... it's too open-ended for the SE format and could do with being pared back to a single core query that can be answered concretely. If necessary break it into multiple Qs, but be sure you do independent research first, tell us what you've looked at and identify exactly what is unclear or you want to improve on in anything you link to.

I like the tenon idea, but have you considered something simple like a biscuit? Or a custom biscuit that's more round than oblong?
